# A problem regarding functional calculus.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $A$ be a Banach Space and $T$ be a bounded operator on $A$. Given that, spectrum of $T$, $\sigma[T]$, is $  F_1 \cup F_2;$ where  $  F_1, F_2$ are disjoint closed set in complex plane.
>   Show that there exist topologically complemented subspace $A_1,A_2$ of $A$ such that $A_1,A_2$ are invariant subspace for $T$ and $\sigma(T|A_i)=F_i$ for $i=1,2.$

Until now what I have done is, taking disjoint open set $G_i$ containing $F_i$ and have chosen $f_i= 1_{G_i}-$ the characteristic function on $G_i$, (which are actually analytic on $G_1\cup G_2$). Then I have taken $A_i$ as range of the projection $f_i(T)$, using the functional calculus for $T$.

Using the spectral mapping theorem one can tell that, $\sigma(Tf_i(T))= F_i\cup$ {$0$}. If my guess is correct then I have to show  $\sigma(Tf_i(T)|A_i)= F_i$. At this stage I need help.

Comment: Where have learned about Borel functional calculus for arbitrary Banach spaces and arbitrary bounded operators?

Comment: learned from Conway's A course in a Functional Analysis.

Comment: In this case see proposition 4.11 Chepter VII. Here you can find a mathod how to "extract" $\{0\}$

Comment: @Norbert: Conway calls it "Riesz Functional Calculus". It works on any unital Banach algebra.

Comment: @MartinArgerami For the moment I thought that $f_i$ is only Borel function and we can't apply holomorphic functional calculus.

Comment: What is $\sigma(T \mid A_i)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0\in F_i$, you are done. Otherwise, as $F_i$ is compact, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|z|>\delta$ for all $z\in F_i$. Then the function $g:z\mapsto zf_i(z)$ satisfies $|g(z)|\geq\delta$ for all $z\in F_i$ and so $h=1/g$ is well-defined and analytic on $F_i$. This implies that $Tf_i(T)|_{A_i}$ is invertible (with inverse $h(T)$), and so $0\not\in\sigma(T|_{A_i})$.

Comment: I have just one doubt that how i will show F_1 is a subset of spectrum of T|A_1.

Comment: If $\lambda\in F_1$, then you can repeat the proof in the answer to show that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible when restricted to $A_2$. This forces $T-\lambda I$ to be non-invertible on $A_1$, as otherwise it would be invertible everywhere contradicting that $\lambda$ is in the spectrum.

Comment: I am now working on this problem several years after your answer has been posted. I appreciate your insight. But I am wondering, could you clarify why it is enough for us to know merely that $h$ is well-defined and analytic on $F_i$? To use $h$ with functional calculus, I thought that we need to know that $h$ is analytic on a neighborhood which contains the whole spectrum of some particular operator. So I'm wondering which operator has just $F_i$ as its spectrum? Any clarification you can give me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Properly, $h$ is defined as $1/g$ on $F_i$ and as for example as the identity $h(z)=z$ on the other one. As $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$, $h$ is analytic. Then you have $$h(T)\,T|_{A_i}=h(T)\,Tf_i(T)|_{A_i}=f_i(T),
$$
which is the identity on $A_i$. So $T|_{A_i}$ is invertible (as an operator on $A_i$).